# How to crop an image and set its cropping bounds from the original image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I've a `UIImageView *userImage` whose size is full screen and `UIImageView *imageSquare` whose size is 320x320. The user will be able to play with `userImage` to make it bigger, change position, etc. `imageSquare` is static and should be seen as *the cropping view*

The code below can crop `userImage` as the `imageSquare.frame.size`. My problem is that it crops it from the top of `userImage` and not from `imageSquare.frame.origin`, meaning *I need to crop it from X and Y coordinates*. It's my first time trying to do this and every things I've tried so far can't make it crop from `imageSquare.frame.origin`.

How could I crop the current view (*the one the user is manipulating*) of `userImage` from `imageSquare.frame.origin`?

```
CGSize pageSize = imageSquare.frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageSize);

    CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(resizedContext, userImage.frame.origin.x, userImage.frame.origin.y);

    [userImage.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (image != nil) {
        NSLog(@"is not nil");
        NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        imageSquare.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imgData];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to translate by *negative* `x` and `y`:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(resizedContext,
                      -userImage.frame.origin.x,
                      -userImage.frame.origin.y);
[userImage.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
```